# accessing nth element in array

Tags: memory, assembly, arm

I'm translating the pseudocode

```
for(i=1; i<MAX; i++)
    if(split[j] = 1)
        for(j=i*3; j<MAX; j=j+i)
            split[j]=0
```

into ARM assembly. Honestly I'm not sure how to do this and it would be a waste of time to show my attempt.

Comment: It depends on the type of `split`. Is it an array of bytes? Ints? Longs? Chars? Since you're using `ldr` I'd assume it's a word. To be absolutely sure, I'd check the memory using a debugger. Also, you don't need to load into R2 and then immediately set it to 0: just set it to 0 and store it.

Comment: In the data section split is declared as '.skip' followed by an expression that evaluates to 400. If that's not what you're asking I'm unclear?

Comment: He's asking what you are storing in the array. From your example it could be: bytes, words, double words, doubles, pointers, etc. Knowing this is important when writing assembly.

Comment: Hmm, your loop doesn't make sense too me. What is "for(j=i*3 to 10)" supposed to do when i>3?

Comment: @Sparafusile Well I guess it would be int but I didn't know such types applied at the assembly level

Comment: @Masta79 I changed it, hopefuly it makes more sense

Comment: @Celeritas I'm sorry, but it still doesn't look like what you really want to do. Your pseudocode currently says "Overwrite everything from  split[3] to split[MAX] with 0". For your original question, X would depend on the datatype used in split. But in the end you would not use mult anyway, because its a very inefficient method to walk through an array, the ARM ISA allows for far better ways. So please, either give us an actual piece of C-Code or pseudocode which makes sense, then we can provide a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the mistakes I found in your code is that you are storing zero in a register and NOT to the address it points to.

```
ldr R2, [R1, R0]
mov R2, #0 ; This is wrong. You are zeroing a register and not the address to 
           ; which it points to
```

Here  is the assembly equivalent for your assembly with comments

```
for(i=1; i<MAX; i++)
    for(j=i*3; j<MAX; j=j+i)
        split[j]=0

           ldr r0,=split
           ldr r4, =MAX
           xor r5,r5  ; this is the zero we shall store into split[j]  

           mov r2, #1 ; i
outer_loop cmp r2,r4 ; i<MAX
           bge end_loop1
           add r1, r2, r2, lsl #1 ; j=i*2+i
inner_loop cmp r1, r4 ; j<MAX
           bge end_loop2
           str r5,[r0], r1, lsl #2 ;split[j]=0
           add r1,r1,r2 ; j=j+i
           b inner_loop
end_loop2  add r2,r2,#1 ; i++
           b outer_loop

end_loop1  end
```

Comment: The main point is, that it does not really answer the original question. Also the code is wrong and inefficient. Your advancing byte-wise, but store word-wise. Also r5 could be set once before outer_loop. The mov+mult could be replaced with a lot more efficient add r1, r2, r2, lsl #1 But that would still not be how you solve such problems with the ARM ISA.

Comment: I agree code is inefficient cos I've written it just for illustration purposes. But I dont think it is wrong. I've assumed `split` to be an integer array as the OP hasn't mentioned anything about it. That is why I'm storing a word. Apart from that, I dint get what you mean when you say "Your advancing byte-wise, but store word-wise" Also I've even mentioned what was wrong in the OPs method

Comment: Your code does not take the store-size of an int into account. You're just counting upwards (r1=r1+r2) without adjusting for split being and array of ints. So your first store of the inner loop will write into memory locations 3,4,5,6 (i=1 j=i*3) and the next into 4,5,6,7 (j=i*3+i) and so on. What you want is writing to 12,13,14,15 and 16,17,18,19. I hope that explains it. Depending on the actual ARM Architecture version the word-store to an unaligned address will also cause data aborts.

Comment: @Masta79 Thanks for the inputs. I dint see that integer adjustment. I've corrected now. Feel free to edit if you wanna add anything more or correct something else